# read an column content with text

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I read a sql answer, but the results with fields contain spaces, so the read command associates each space as a separator, how can I retrieve each field all alone

```
req="select col1, col2, col3 from table where condition;"


mysql -D database -u root -h localhost -p$MYSQL_PASS -e "$req" | while read col1, col2, col3
do
  echo "col1 : $col1"
  echo "col2 : $col2"
  echo "col3 : $col3"  
done
```

So the content of

```
col1 = "word1 word2 word3"
col2 = "word4 word5 word6"
col3 = "word7 word8 word9"
```

The output of the script is :

```
col1 : word1
col2 : word2
col3 : word3
```

Any ideas ? thanks guys.

Comment: Add output of your mysql command to your question.

Comment: call sql 3 times woth 1 output column, of `select col1, '@', col2, '@', col3 ..` with @ an unique character (not in col1,2,3) and use IFS='@' when reading the results.

Comment: i have changed but not worked, i have not well write it, you can see it http://hastebin.com/ujiseveqip.bash